# What does "incidental remark" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "incidental remark" mean off-topic or occasional or something quite different?

> For the purpose of giving information my summary is scant; and, as I have already said, many of Schopenhauer’s incidental remarks are just and illuminating.

After a couple of paragraphs, he says,

> Schopenhauer, like Croce, shows in many incidental references, more, not less, sensitiveness to works of art than most philosophers.

Comment: What did you find when you looked up “incidental” in the dictionary, and why didn’t that help?

Comment: That depends on how the term is used. Please give context, at least as full sentence, and preferably a paragraph.

Comment: "For the purpose of giving information my summary is scant;
and, as I have already said, many of Schopenhauer’s incidental remarks
are just and illuminating." After a couple of paragraphs, he says, "Schopenhauer, like Croce, shows in many incidental references,
more, not less, sensitiveness to works of art than most
philosophers."

Comment: This appears to come from http://ddong.narod.ru/deweyen2/txt12.htm Art and Experience by John Dewy  In future please indicate a source when one is known.

Answer (score 1):

In this usage "incidental"  means "by the way" or not part of the main focus of the text. An Incidental remark, in this sense, would be one not essential to the argument or point being made by Schopenhauer.

As the comment by  Lucian Sava mentions, the word "tangential" could have been used in place of  "incidental" here withe essentially the same meaning.

Comment: As a supplement to your accurate answer I'd say *tangential*.